# Como fazer um bulk update com duas chaves primárias no stored procedure do mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Preciso executar um update inúmeros vezes, conforme a seguir:

```
UPDATE my_table set column1='value1', column2='value2' where primary_key1=1 and primary_key2=2;

UPDATE my_table set column1='value3', column2='value4' where primary_key1=3 and primary_key2=4;

UPDATE my_table set column1='value5', column2='value6' where primary_key1=5 and primary_key2=6;

.
.
.

UPDATE my_table set column1='valueX', column2='valueY' where primary_key1=W and primary_key2=Z;
```

Como realizo esse processo in bulk no stored procedure de um banco mysql? É possível?

Comment: Você gostaria de fazer esse processo em um loop utilizando por exemplo um foreach? Passar os valores a serem alterados por parâmetro ou obter através de um select?

Comment: Quero executar essa query apenas uma vez e realizar multiplos updates. Se a tabela tiver apenas uma chave primária, é bem tranquilo. Minha dúvida é quando há chave primária composta.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução, seria utilizar INSERT com ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Ele tentará realizar um insert e, se for um registro duplicado, ele atualiza o ultimo registro.

Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4)
VALUES
(1,1,'val','val'),
(1,2,'val','val'),
(1,3,'val','val'),
(2,1,'val','val'),
(2,2,'val','val'),
(2,3,'val','val')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE column_3=values(column_3), column_4=values(column_4);
```

Sendo a column 1 e 2 as keys.

Comment: Agora preciso descobrir como fazer isso numa stored procedure.